# Matlab: Create RGB matrix depending on values in 2 other matrices

Tags: image, matlab, matrix, rgb

sorry for the stupid question. I want to define an RGB image in matlab depending on the values in two matrices. e.g.:

```
  A       B         comparision RGB
|1 0|   |1 0|  -->  |green    red  |
|1 0|   |0 1|  -->  |purple   cyan |
```

The following code does the job but is **very slow** (I know):

```
comparision = uint8(zeros([H,W, 3])); 
for i=1:H
  for j=1:W
    if (A(i,j)==1 && B(i,j)==1) %tp
        comparision (i,j,:) = [113 140 0];
    end
    if (A(i,j)==0 && B(i,j)==0) %tn
        comparision (i,j,:) = [200 40 41];
    end
    if (A(i,j)==0 && B(i,j)==1) %fp (false alarm)
        comparision (i,j,:) = [10 130 120];
    end
    if (A(i,j)==1 && B(i,j)==0) %fn 
        comparision (i,j,:) = [120 20 120];
    end
  end
end
```

I'm pretty sure it can be done a lot faster using matlab matrix functionality. Unfortunately I'm always a bit confused about the matlab notation and was not successful googling :-/.

I tried something like this:

```
comparision(LabelImage1 == 1 & LabelImage2 == 1) = [255 0 0]
```

But it didn't work out.

Can anybody help me doing it **faster**? Thanks in advance

Comment: What's the difference between third and fourth conditions? They both have `A(i,j)==0 && B(i,j)==1`.

Comment: Ohh, thanks! Thats just a typo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can convert the values `A, B` to indices and then use `ind2rgb` to map those indices to colors:

```
indImg = uint8(A.*2 + B);   % generate indices [0..3]
cMap = [1, 0, 0;   % red
        0, 1, 1;   % cyan
        1, 0, 1;   % magenta
        0, 1, 0];  % green
comparison = ind2rgb(indImg, cMap);   % convert indices to cMap RGB values
```

An [indexed image](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/image-types.html#f2-155) is one in which each pixel value is an (integer) index into a [color map](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colormap.html) rather than an RGB or grayscale value. You can display this kind of image directly using `imshow`:

```
imshow(indImg, cMap)
```

An indexed image of type `uint8` or `uint16` is the one situation I know of where MATLAB uses 0-based indexing, which is why the indices above are `[0..3]` and why @Divakar's alternate solution in the comments had to use `indImg+1`.

The function [ind2rgb](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ind2rgb.html) simply takes each of these indices and replaces them with the 3D RGB value, each of which would be something like `permute(cMap(index), [1 3 2])`.

---

For more speed, here's an amusing option:

```
comparison = cat(3, ~B, B, xor(A,B));
```

(you might have to cast that to a `double`, I'm not sure...)

[Here](http://ideone.com/vGsFbW) is a simple comparison on ideone using this approach, my original code, and Divakar's suggestion. I couldn't get the image size above 2000x2000 due to memory limitations of the online interpreter, but this approach seems to be at least twice as fast as the others.

Comment: Simply indexing could be faster - `reshape(cMap(indImg+1,:),H,W,[])`?

Comment: @Divakar Yes, but not as clear what you're doing, imho.

Comment: Well we are just selecting rows off `cMap` based on the indices and then reshaping to basically push off the three elements per index into the third dim.

Comment: @Divakar Yeah, I understand what you're doing, both of them are mapping indices to RGB vectors, but I think it's more immediate to understand that `ind2rgb` is doing that rather than `reshape`. Either one is going to be nearly instantaneous on displayable image sizes.

Comment: For completeness I'd include a link to an explanation of what [indexed images](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/image-types.html) are.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I understand it (thanks for the details) and I tried it.
I got down from 140s to about 8s. Any more ideas how to speed it more. In another operation on the same image I need below 3 seconds for an operation like this:
    A(C(:,:,2) == 0)

Comment: @CaptIglu The code running is a function of the size of your image.  Are you running this on very high resolution images?  If you are, this is as fast as you're going to get it.

Comment: CaptIglu, If you're using very large images, try @Divakar's solution in the first comment. As mentioned, it might be faster. Also, is there a possibility to change the mapping between the logical values and the colors?

Comment: @Divakar I've added an ideone link with basic timings. I couldn't get the image sizes above 2000x2000, but your approach was slightly faster than my original. The new one is about twice as fast, though.

Comment: Oh yes, I do! The images are up to 100MP (sorry for missing to mention it)

It woulb be possible to change the mapping between values and colors. I will try the proposed solution. thanks a lot!

by the way...which functions takes long about 7 of the 8 sec is the: ind2rgb()

Comment: @CaptIglu Yes, `ind2rgb` is doing all of the actual work, so it makes sense that it's taking the most time. Hopefully the new approach will be faster for you.